# Can I overload /usr/bin/python to dump any exception in program execution into a database in addition to displaying it on stdout?

Tags: python

I have control over what goes into /usr/bin/python and can replace it with my script which calls python underneath. However, I do not have control on the programs that are written (cannot mandate a particular convention etc.)
In such a situation, what would be the best way to have python dump the stacktrace into a database in addition to displaying it on stdout? (Have your own script?)

Update:
Clarification: I meant a stacktrace that a program generates upon error:

> > > l = [1,2,3]
> > >       l[4]
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       IndexError: list index out of range

Solution: I think AKX's solution below works in redirecting stderr to a script which dumps the stacktrace into a NoSQL store. Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify which stacktrace you are talking about?  Also, what type of database do you wish to use?

Comment: For what it's worth, Python actually prints exceptions out on stderr, not stdout, so if you can control how Python is executed, you can redirect stderr to a script that writes its input into a database.

Comment: Are you hoping to capture exceptions that the program silently handles, and that never appear on any output?

Comment: What do you mean by **mandating a particular converntion**?

Answer (score 0):

You can define default exception handler:

```
import sys
import traceback


def my_handler(typ, value, tb):
    error_str = traceback.format_exception(typ, value, tb)
    print 'Here you can write exception to DB: ', error_str
sys.excepthook = my_handler

print 1 / 0  # here you can execute third party code via execfile/import
```

Look into documentation about [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) and [generating tracebacks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception).